# Descobrir o tamanho de um diretório

Tags: java

Gostaria de saber se seria possível descobrir o tamanho de um diretório em **JAVA**.

Tenho uma pasta cache em meu sistema e gostaria de fazer uma função para sempre que essa pasta excedesse um tamanho pré-definido eu pudesse fazer uma limpeza na mesma, porém não sei como ver o tamanho do diretório em especifico!

Já procurei em vários fóruns e não encontrei nenhum exemplo pratico que me tirasse essa duvida.

Comment: Removi saudações e agradecimentos conforme orientado aqui: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/846/saudações-e-agradecimentos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O tamanho do diretório é e sempre será 0, pois, os diretórios são apenas reservatórios!

Testa essa função, não é de minha autoria, mas funciona ate que legal!

```
import java.io.*;  

class TamanhoAproximadoDiretorio {  
    /** 
     * Percorre um diretório e soma os tamanhos dos arquivos. 
     * @param dir Um diretório.  
     * @return A soma dos tamanhos dos arquivos no diretório e subdiretórios, em bytes. 
     */  
    long tamanho (File dir) {  
        long ret = 0;  
        for (File f : dir.listFiles()) {  
            if (f.isDirectory()) {  
                ret += tamanho (f);  
            } else {  
                ret += f.length();  
            }  
        }  
        return ret;  
    }  

  public static void main(String[] args) {  
    if (args.length < 1) {  
        System.out.println ("Sintaxe: java -cp . TamanhoAproximado diretorio");  
        System.exit (1);  
    }  
    TamanhoAproximadoDiretorio t = new TamanhoAproximadoDiretorio();  
    File dir = new File (args[0]);  
    // Aqui estou mostrando o tamanho usando a definição do Windows (1 MB = 1024 KB = 1.048.576 bytes)  
    System.out.printf ("O diretório %s (e seus subdiretórios) ocupa %.3f megabytes%n", args[0], t.tamanho (dir) / 1048576.0);  
}
```

}

Outra que também pode te ajudar, descubra qual se encaixa nas suas condições:

```
public static int getFolderSize(String path)  {     
File folder = new File(path);     
int size = 0;     
if (folder.isDirectory()) {     
    String[] dirList = folder.list();     
    if (dirList != null) {     
        for (int i = 0; i < dirList.length; i++) {     
            String fileName = dirList[i];     
            File f = new File(path, fileName);     
            if (f.isDirectory()) {     
                String filePath = f.getPath();     
                size += getFolderSize(filePath);     
                continue;     
            }     
            size += f.length();     
        }     
    }     
}     
return size;
```